# Optimizing my Django app on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, optimization

I'm optimising a particular use case of my Django app. My first step was to replace a `QuerySet` with a `ValuesQuerySet`. This worked quite well but I want to do more. Now I'm considering using Memcache (the app is running on Google App Engine). So my plan is to basically put the `ValuesQuerySet` in Memcache. However it is my understanding that `ValueQuerySet` is basically a not yet materialised data structure. In order for the cache to work, the `ValueQuerySet` needs to materialise first and then put in the Memcache.

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

```
list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it.
```

and:

```
Finally, note a ValuesQuerySet is a subclass of QuerySet, so it has all methods of QuerySet.
```

But when I try `my_values_qs.list()` it throws an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'ValuesQuerySet' object has no attribute 'list'
```

So, although `ValuesQuerySet` is a subclass of `QuerySet` it apparently cannot `list()` its contents. Which, if true, would mean that the Django docs are wrong or at least misleading.

Am I missing something or are the docs indeed wrong? What would be the best way to materialise the result of `ValueQuerySet` so that I can store it in Memcache?

Comment: Refer to this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misreading that bit from the docs. It doesn't say "call the `queryset.list()` method": it says "call `list()` on it". In other words, call `list(my_queryset)`, not `my_queryset.list()` - and in fact that is explicitly illustrated with an example immediately afterwards.

Note that this has nothing to do with subclassing: `QuerySet` doesn't have a `list()` method either.

Comment: You're right. Big error. The routines mentioned are functions and not methods. I should have paid more attention to the provided sample.... :-\