# Optimizing Django app in Google App Engine

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine

I am facing slow page load time (list page in Django admin) for a simple Django app, deployed on Google App Engine, with postgres Cloud SQL. There are fewer than 20 records. SQL time is negligible, even with 30 queries.

[image]

Majority of the time is shown as `domLoading`
[image]

I assume that `domLoading` is probably referring to the initial loading of the `case/` page, which took 3 seconds.

Most of the solutions online refer to tweaking apache/nginx settings. But since I am using Google App Engine (PaaS), I cannot directly control webserver settings. `gcloud app deploy` is supposed to handle the load-balancing and code versioning.

How do I improve the basic load time of Django App on GAE? Both GAE and Cloud SQL are hosted in the same region.

PS: I did find some answers like [Optimizing my Django app on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787842/optimizing-my-django-app-on-google-app-engine), but they refer to optimizing SQL queries, which is not the case here.

Comment: domLoading happens in the browser "after" it has received the text and while it is converting it to a DOM tree structure.

Comment: @thebjorn Agree. But the math doesn't add up. Chrome Dev tool shows that the page load itself took 2.84 Secs. Intuitively, `domLoading` time includes it. If page load time is reduced, domLoading should also come down.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to not having any available instances since that's about the time it takes for an instance to be deployed. You could use [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests) to improve performance in this case. If that doesn't work for you, you can use [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/want-to-know-why-your-application-is-slow-cloud-traces-new-features-can-help) to analyze the requests and isolate the issue.